# Download pdf asynchronously

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, download, amazon-s3, pdf-generation

When a user clicks on a links in my Ruby on Rails app, a PDF file is generated in background.

The app is polling the server to know when the PDF file is ready, and then it should ask the user to download it as if he clicked on a PDF link that already existed.

We do this with an hidden `iframe` and change the `src` attribute when the PDF file is ready.

While it works on Firefox (there's a native pop up for downloading the file), it does not on safari/chrome. How should I do this? I've seen there's a [Content-Disposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers#Responses) HTTP header, but the PDF file is stored on S3, so I don't think I can use that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need to use the `Content-Disposition = 'attachment';` response header.

I'm not totally up to the play with S3 so let me know if this answer isn't quite right but it seems you **are** able to set the content headers in the request URL now, see example [here.](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html?r=7768#ExampleGetReqAlterResponseHeaders)

Comment: Indeed, I am and it seems to do the trick. Just have to integrate it with paperclip/fog now !